# How to load index.php instead of index.html only for my IP address?

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

When building a Joomla site, I often add a simple "coming soon" page as "index.html" to be loaded as default, and then I visit `example.com/index.php` to load Joomla.

Is it possible to add a rule to .htaccess in order to load the "index.php" file only for my own IP address?

(I want to do this because the "Home" link in Joomla loads the "coming soon" page, and then I have to add "index.php" each time I want to see the main home page.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicholas K. Dionysopoulos from Akeeba tends to be a good one to follow for site maintenance and security discussion...
http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-feb-2011/item/378-how-offline-is-joomla-offline-mode

The specific code from that article:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /$rewrite_base 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !123\.123\.123\.123 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !offline\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.swf|\.css|\.js)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) offline.html    [R=307,L]
```

(Also, I tend to work on a demo server myself, but I'm pretty sure that offline mode allows someone to still see the site if they are logged in as a super admin, so you may not actually need to touch htaccess at all.  You can style this page in your template's offline.php file. )

Comment: That looks like a better approach, and it's almost working, but non-authorized users are redirected to `example.com/$rewrite_base/offline.html`

Comment: What if you get rid of the RewriteBase /$rewrite_base line?  Or try RewriteBase / instead.

Comment: Yes, changing `RewriteBase /$rewrite_base` to `RewriteBase /` works fine, this is the answer to my question :)
BTW, I tend to avoid Joomla offline mode because I often need to see what the site looks like to visitors when not logged in.

Comment: There is actually a separate permission to see offline site, which will allow you to allow people who are not super admins to login to the site. It's in global configuration.

Comment: Thank you Elin, I was not aware of that option in Joomla. It might come in handy during development.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a rewrite based on your IP, which should be available in the HTTP header REMOTE_ADDR

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.456\.789\.0$
RewriteRule ^http://yourdomain.com/$ /index.php [R]
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives me a Redirect Loop error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using index.html put it in an offline.php file and put that file in your template folder, top level. Then set the site to offline and you'll have to login to see it. That way curious people can't poke around.